# ElasticSearch: Getting all values for nested field

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new to ElasticSearch, working with v5.1.2 trying to get all values of a nested field, in my example the values in `firstname`. My data:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [
    {
      "firstname" : "John",
      "lastname" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstname" : "Alice",
      "lastname" :  "White"
    },
    {
      "lastname": "Muller" 
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want my query result to be the first names "John" and "Alice".
I tried with several aggregation queries for example:

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "myagg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.firstname"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but no success. How can I make this sort of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first declare a [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) for your index with user as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html) field

```
PUT my_index3
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "firstname":{
              "type":"keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT my_index3/my_type/1
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [
    {
      "firstname" : "John",
      "lastname" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstname" : "Alice",
      "lastname" :  "White"
    },
    {
      "lastname": "Muller" 
    }
  ]
}
```

After declaring mappings you can use [nested aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) like the following.

```
POST my_index3/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_user": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "firstname": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user.firstname",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps